# Can VIM automatically close NERDTree when deleting a buffer?

Tags: vim, nerdtree

**Problem:**

- In VIM, open NERDTree
- Select a file and open it in a new buffer (Enter)
- Do some work on buffer and save it
- Delete buffer with :bd

Now NERDTree takes up the whole window - this isn't a problem per se, but...

- Go to next buffer with :bnext
- Continue working
- Now try opening NERDTree again by hitting Ctrl-N

You see, NERDTree stays "maximised" and you have to resize it.

**My attempt at solving this issue:**

My approach was what is stated in the title: close NERDTree automatically when deleting a buffer, then reopen it when entering another.

```
function! g:CloseNERDTree()
  if exists("g:NERDTree") && g:NERDTree.IsOpen()
    NERDTreeClose
  else
    echo "already closed"
  endif
endfunction
autocmd BufDelete * call CloseNERDTree()

function! g:OpenNERDTree()
  if exists("g:NERDTree") && g:NERDTree.IsOpen()
    echo "already open"
  else
    NERDTree
  endif
endfunction
autocmd BufEnter * call OpenNERDTree()
```

This causes VIM to become unusable and my VimScript knowledge isn't enough to know what's going on.

Comment: Not an answer but always worth reading: http://vimcasts.org/blog/2013/01/oil-and-vinegar-split-windows-and-project-drawer/

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your particular problem (for me, NERDTree always opens in a sidebar), but I think the (or one) problem with your approach is with the `BufDelete` event. [`:help BufDelete`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#BufDelete) has the following caveat:

> Don't change to another buffer, it will cause problems.

I think it would be better to trigger on [`WinEnter`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#WinEnter), and use the number of visible windows (`winnr('$')`) for the check, like this (untested):

```
function! OnWinEnter()
    if winnr('$') == 1
        if exists("g:NERDTree") && g:NERDTree.IsOpen()
            NERDTreeClose
        endif
    else
        if ! (exists("g:NERDTree") && g:NERDTree.IsOpen())
            NERDTreeOpen
        endif
    endif
endfunction
autocmd WinEnter * call OnWinEnter()
```